# Posting on a Facebook page, privacy settings and graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, settings, privacy

I have a comapny Facebook page wherein users can first "like" and then post messages. When I post as a user who has the switched off the Platform features (via Privacy settings -> Ads, Apps and Websites) to this page and use the graph API / real-stream API to access the posts from this page, my afore mentioned post is not returned (as expected -> due to the user privacy settings).

Is there anyway of knowing (via API) that a user has posted, but has strong privacy settings, due to which I am not getting any posts?

Comment: There was a discussion about this recently on the Facebook developers group, and the conclusion was, that a user that has “opted-out of the platform” is not visible _at all_ to apps – they don’t show up in friends list, there postings/comments are not visible, etc.

Comment: @CBroe do you have the link to the group thread?